# Zendesk - How to include custom js file in client side app?

Tags: zendesk, zendesk-app

I am trying create Clint side in Zendesk framework.
I want to include custom js file to perform some action (to keep it separate).

> directory structure

```
app-folder
    assets
        iframe.html
        .
        .
    sevices
        userServices.js
    tmp
    translations
        en.json
    manifest.json
```

I have included file like following (in iframe.html)

```
<script src="/base-app/services/userServices.js"></script>
```

i am getting following error

> GET http://localhost:4567/base-app/services/userServices.js
> net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the 'services' folder under 'assets' and update the script tag to

```
<script src="services/userServices.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have already fix with same. Thanks for the response @ahmedsabriz